# Can gnuplot accept 3 or more time parameters?

Tags: 3d, gnuplot, projection, parametric-equations

I'd like to plot this equation:

```
x(t,u,v) = ((cos(u)+2)cos(v))cos(a) + ((sin(u)+2)cos(t))sin(a)

y(u,v) = (cos(u)+2)sin(v)

z(t,u) = (sin(u)+2)sin(t)
```

I haven't seen any examples of someone using 3 parameters, but it seems like it would be possible. It produces the projection of a rotating 4D torus.